# How to resize shader area?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I made 2d outline shader but The outline does not render beyond the boundary of the sprite.

so I need to resize shader area.

Is there a simple way to solve it, other than remaking sprites and changing positions in the vertex shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you can only draw within the geometry of your object.

In theory, you could tweak the geometry in the shader to expand the border but I have no idea how to do it reliably.

Almost all of the edge shaders I'm aware of use a full-screen post-processing pass to render outlines